# What is the difference between an App and Application in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any difference between `App` and `Application` in c#?

I am trying to use `App.current.Resources` in control library which is loaded in main `WPF` application. But it is not possible in a straight way, but at the same time it is allowing me to use `Application.current.Resources`

Could anyone help me to understand the basic differences between these two. 
Is there any flaw on using `Application.Current.Resources` instead of `App.current.Resources`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`App` is the default class name for your `Application`. It will be defined in your project by autogenerated code as follows.

```
public partial class App : Application
```

So indeed both are same, You're accessing static `Current` property defined in `Application` class only.

```
Application.Current.Resources//Accessing current through base class
App.Current.Resources//Accessing current through derived class
```